# Python - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

Why would data['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url'] would produce 'IndexError: list index out of range' error? I understand what this error means but can't see why? perhaps too sleepy at 2 am? Please help

```
data = {
u'entities': {
    u'symbols': [], 
    u'user_mentions': [],
    u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [3, 13], u'text': u'firstpost'},
                  {u'indices': [22, 35], u'text': u'snowinginnyc'}],
    u'urls': [{u'url': u'https://t.co/0sClwIMXKW', 
               u'indices': [36, 59],
               u'expanded_url': u'https://vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD',
               u'display_url': u'vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD'}
             ]
}},
```

Comment: Is there another set of braces you're not showing?  That's not a valid python data structure.

Comment: @roippi - Yes, you're right. I missed one braces. Why downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're still not showing us what `data` really is.  `data['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']` gives a `TypeError` because data is a *tuple*.  The trailing comma makes it so.

Comment: Run `pprint.pprint(data)` and copy/paste what that shows you, since you're still not showing us the actual data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a valid python code, u are missing braces. Here :

```
data = {
u'entities': {
    u'symbols': [], 
    u'user_mentions': [],
    u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [3, 13], u'text': u'firstpost'},
                  {u'indices': [22, 35], u'text': u'snowinginnyc'}],
    u'urls': [{u'url': u'https://t.co/0sClwIMXKW', 
               u'indices': [36, 59],
               u'expanded_url': u'https://vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD',
               u'display_url': u'vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD'}
             ]
}
}
```

and `print data['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']`

prints vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {u'entities': {
    u'symbols': [], 
    u'user_mentions': [],
    u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [3, 13], u'text': u'firstpost'},
                  {u'indices': [22, 35], u'text': u'snowinginnyc'}],
    u'urls': [{u'url': u'https://t.co/0sClwIMXKW', 
               u'indices': [36, 59],
               u'expanded_url': u'https://vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD',
               u'display_url': u'vine.co/v/hQPlQ9l5XDD'}
             ]
}}        
print data['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']
```