# Python Tkinter IndexError: List out of range

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I am making a meal planning application that allows you to set ingredients you have and recipes and gives you a grocery list based on it.
When I run it, however, I get these errors:

```
IndexError: list index out of range 
Exception in Tkinter callback
...
Line 15: recipes[row-1].append(recipeIngredient): IndexError: list index out of range
File "/Users/*****/Documents/shopping planner.py"
```

I have looked at this question, but it doesn't answer my question:
[Python - IndexError: list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512458/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

Here's my code:

```
def MkRecipe():
    recipe_creator = tkinter.Button(window, text=" ", command=MkIngredient(len(recipes)))
    recipe_creator.grid(row=1, column=(len(recipes)+1))
    recipes.append([])
def mkIngredient(row):
    recipeIngredient = tkinter.Entry()
    recipes[row-1].append(recipeIngredient)
    recipeIngredient.grid(row=len(recipes[row]), column=row)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire error? I think you've cropped out the useful info.

Comment: I'll try. Some technology problems are preventing me from copying and pasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ln = len(recipe)`,`recipe_creator = tkinter.Button(text=" ", command=lambda: MkIngredient(ln))`, and `recipeIngredient.grid(row=len(recipes[row-1])+1, column=row)`. The problem is that you are running the function on button creation.